# docker not running despite running on foreground and -it options

Tags: docker

I have an application that utilizes Apache2/Tomcat on Ubuntu container.
It has scripts in "/etc/init.d/apatomcat"

This is my Dockerfile:

This is what I do on cmd I tried (including -D option with foreground, etc).

docker start & attach

docker run & exect

```
root@docker:~/tomcat-Docker/ubuntu# cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ENV http_proxy 'http://wsa.corp.com:8000'
ENV https_proxy 'http://wsa.corp.com:8000'
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive 
ENV apatomcat_DIR=/var/apatomcat/apatomcat/
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

COPY apt.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y vim python2.7 openjdk-7-jdk ssh ant 

CMD chmod a+rwx /etc/profile.d/apatomcat.sh

COPY apatomcat.conf /etc/apatomcat/apatomcat.conf

CMD /etc/init.d/apatomcat start &
CMD /etc/init.d/ssh restart &

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && bash
root@docker9:~/tomcat-Docker/ubuntu# docker build -t apatomcat .

docker start 9e1752bf7650  
docker attach 9e1752bf7650

root@docker:~/tomcat-Docker/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES



root@docker:~/tomcat-Docker/ubuntu# docker run -i -t apatomcat  /bin/bash
root@docker:~/tomcat-Docker/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Despite reading up on countless articles, still don't seem to stay on and shutting down.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three mistakes in your Dockerfile.

First of all, when creating Docker containers, you don't need to use SysVinit, systemd, etc to manage processes. Actually, using them normally causes more harm than good. The Docker daemon will keep the container running as long as a process is running in the foreground. In your case, you're invoking a SysVinit script, and the script will exit as soon as the daemon is started. It doesn't matter that you've added a "&" at the end: the command doesn't run in bash, so it doesn't make any difference. Just invoke the Tomcat server and make it run in foreground!

The second problem is with SSH. As a rule of thumb, you should never run sshd inside a container: if you need to connect to a shell inside the container, first connect to the host using ssh, then attach yourself to a running container (`docker exec -it container_name bash`). Your setup is "wrong" also because containers should be running one and just one process only. If you really need a SSH daemon in a container, also, there are some "caveats": see https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/ (however, I would strongly recommend thinking whether you really need sshd inside a container: I can't think of a real reason why you would, unless it's because you need to connect to a process using a SSH tunnel - for example if you're running a VNC server in the container).

Lastly, the entrypoint is not correct too. You shouldn't call "bash" in your entrypoint: just specify one (and just one!) command that will be executed.